# How to add a 360 degree viewer module in my app?

Tags: image, google-street-view, 360-degrees, 360-panorama-viewer

i want add a 360 degree viewer in my app.The panormic image format of the object is available(generated using google street view).

I just need a viewer to display 360 degree images.

Comment: What's your app built upon? Is it a website or mobile app? Different panoramic viewers are suited better for different platforms.

Comment: Its an android app in java(using android studio). I wanna view panormic pictures clicked using Google street view or any other panormic camera apps.

Answer (score 2):

Here are four open source viewers to consider, not in any order of priority: A-Frame, the leading open source project for WebVR, backed by Mozilla, excellent for education projects. Google VR View, works especially well on Daydream and Cardboard. React VR, backed by Facebook and optimized for Facebook apps, it's WebVR API compliant, and works with Carmel Developer Preview browser from Oculus. Photo Sphere Viewer, stable, has been around for a while, most viewer controls. More details here: http://lists.theta360.guide/t/4-top-free-360-image-viewers-for-developers/1391?u=jcasman